# How to do a very simple for loop

Tags: coffeescript

I want to accomplish this in coffeescript:

```
for (i = 0, i < count, i++) {
 doSomething();
} // count is a number
```

But it is always handled as an array.

Is there way to prevent this? I have tried a while loop, but it didn´t work out for me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you want to implement this:

```
for(i = 0; i < count; i++) { ... }
```

in CoffeeScript, not `for(i = 0, ...)`.

There's an example of this sort of thing right in [the documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

```
countdown = (num for num in [10..1])
```

and the JavaScript version:

```
var countdown, num;

countdown = (function() {
  var _i, _results;
  _results = [];
  for (num = _i = 10; _i >= 1; num = --_i) {
    _results.push(num);
  }
  return _results;
})();
```

So you just want to use this:

```
for i in [1..count]
  doSomething()
```

or

```
doSomething() for i in [1..count]
```

Note the the range starts at 1 so that `[1..count]` gives you `count` iterations.

Comment: You´re right - for me the documentation is a little too short-worded. Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: @Rockbot: You have to study the examples as well as the text, shame there's no cookbook section in the docs.